# Javascript code called from VBS throwing unspecified error at runtime

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vbscript, hp-uft

I have a webpage on which I want to add jQuery lib, here is the code :

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src ="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

This code is called from UFT using VBS code :

```
script= "var script = document.createElement('script');" &_
        "script.src =" & chr(34) & "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" & chr(34) & ";" &_
        "document.body.appendChild(script);"
Browser("myBrowser").Page("myPage").RunScript(script)
```

When I run my VBS code, an error is thrown

> "Erreur non spécifiée" | in English "unspecified error"

But i can't figure out why this error is thrown since both VBS and my js code seem OK... I am using IE 8 Enterprise Mode and script is enabled in security options.
I have no more ideas on how to work around this issue...

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried **`RunScriptFromFile`** instead of just **`RunScript`**...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered by [UFT's online documentation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/latest/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Web/WEBPACKAGELib~Page.html#RunScript):

> When running this method, you should use an `eval()` function or anonymous function to run the script entered for this method.
>   For example, you can use functions like these:
>
> ```
> "eval(var remove = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]; var per = remove.parentNode; per.removeChild(remove););"
> ```
>
> OR
>   `"(function(){var remove = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]; var per = remove.parentNode; per.removeChild(remove);})();"`*

Please see the modified code that works with a couple of changes made

1. The code is placed in an [anonymous function and immediately executed (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)
2. I use single quotes instead of `chr(34)` (it doesn't make a difference, just more readable).

   ```
   script = "(function(){" &_ 
     "var script=document.createElement('script');" &_  
     "script.src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js';" &_  
     "document.body.appendChild(script);" &_   
   "})();"
   ```

Comment: Indeed it works ! Thank you so much man I would have never find this alone :)

Comment: Amazing what can happen when you read [the Documentation](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/latest/UFT_Help/Subsystems/FunctionReference/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Web/WEBPACKAGELib~Page.html#RunScript).

Comment: @Lankymart, actually I tried it and looked in Chrome's developer tools and figured it out from there, [Easton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2003136/easton-l) edited the documentation into this answer.